# Ajax url does not change in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, url, refresh

I have been trying to use ajax post to another actionresult.

However i have 3 problems about ajax.

```
1-Url does not change on browser.
2-I can not click to previous page and forward page on browser
3-Do i have to refresh html like  $("#BodyPage").html(mydata);?
```

My codes below,

**Index ActionResult (Project starts from Index)**

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Index View**

```
<body id="BodyPage">

<input type="text" id="LoginEmailText"/>
<input type="text" id="LoginPasswordText"/>

</body>
```

**JS Code:**

```
<script>
    function LoginButton1OnClick() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Login/MainPageRegister",
            cache:false,
            data:
                {
                    LoginEmailText: $("#LoginEmailText").val(),
                    LoginPasswordText: $("#LoginPasswordText").val(),
                },
            success: function (mydata) {
                $("#BodyPage").html(mydata);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**MainPageRegister ActionResult:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MainPageRegister(MyModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**MainPageRegister View:**

```
<h1>Just for an example</h1>
```

My questions,

**1-Why url does not change when i post data ?**

**2-Why i can not go previous and forwards page ?**

**3-Do i always have to refresh like  $("#BodyPage").html(mydata)? Is there another easier way ?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.codemag.com/Article/1301091

Comment: Ther is also this library that can help you http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Comment: thanks for help however i can not do this again i tried


        var pageName = $(this).attr("href");
        window.history.pushState(null, "", pageName);

Comment: may anyone please help me ?

Comment: Google `ajax deep linking` and you will find how to do it