# Change route url in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have Login Controller and Register ActionResult

```
   public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

If i post any data to Register actionresult url seems like below,

```
WebSiteName/Login/Register
```

I want to change route url as **WebSiteName/Login/Reg=Id?**

So i tried below however i could not change route url.

```
   routes.MapRoute(
         name: "something",
         url: "Login/Reg=Id?",
         defaults: new
         {
             controller = "Login",
             action = "Register",
             id = id = UrlParameter.Optional
         }
     );
```

So how can i change url in asp.net mvc ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want your URL to look like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to use incorrect form of a url parameter. The options you have are:

1. Url part parameter: WebSiteName/Login/Reg/{id}

   For this you can use following config

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "something",
        url: "Login/Reg/{id}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Login",
            action = "Register",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
   ```
2. Query string parameter: WebSiteName/Login/Reg?id={id}

   Here you do not need to specify the parameter in config at all:

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "something",
        url: "Login/Reg",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Login",
            action = "Register"
        }
    );
   ```

Of course in both cases it is assumed your action `Register` has parameter id.

Comment: I wrote your code before"Default" Controller Action etc , it worked now.If i wrote your code after "Default" it does not work , i don't know why.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3230063, that can be easily explained. When new request is received, ASP.NET MVC tries to find corresponding route in the routes table, and takes the first match. Default route matches almost everything, so whatever is added to the table after it not likely to be reached. That is why you should add all specific routes before the default one.

Comment: Please help me for this question . 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335361/ajax-url-does-not-change-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Here I've remove last two passing parameter from the URL

this is my url link -> http://localhost:12345/User?value=98998?id=2

and I want to remove value and id parameter from the url link

## Step-I

Modify your Routeconfig.cs like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "User",
   "User/{value}/{id}",
   new { controller = "User", action = "Index", value= UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

## Step-II

User Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string value, int id)
{
    // write Your logic here 
    return view();
}
```

## Step-III

Create an Index view for UserController

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkName", "Index", "User", new {value = "98998", id = "2"},null)
```

Finally we got a result: http://localhost:12345/User/98998/2

Likewise we can remove multiple parameter from the url